# Make ASP.NET MVC Controller/Model use Local Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, offline-caching

I am starting to work on using Local Storage for my ASP.NET MVC/Web API application. (I am very new to all technologies being used here.)

The application allows a user when in the office to select the run sheet (list of packages to be delivered) and then a copy of all the data for that run sheet gets stored in the local storage of the browser. The user then delivers all the packages, recording the deliveries in local storage and upon returning to the office all the deliveries are transferred from local storage to the database on the server. Or at least that is how it is supposed to work. :)

I am getting all the run sheet details from the database and displaying them, no problem, the first time using this code:

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid id)
{
    RunSheetDetailsListViewModel vm = new RunSheetDetailsListViewModel();
    var query = this._unit.RunSheetDetails.GetByRunSheetId(id);
    vm.RunSheetDetails = query.ToList();

    return View("Index", vm);
}
```

In my Index.cshtml I have this:

```
    var vm = new ViewModel();

    var serialized = JSON.stringify(vm.runSheetDetails());

    runsheetdetailsDataService.saveLocal(serialized);
```

in the jquery ready function.

This apparently saves the data properly in the local storage.

Now, when the user is not connected to the server, how do I tell the Index ActionResult to pull the data from local storage rather than the database?

Comment: Your controller or the Index action knows nothing about your client or browser, so you have to handle this clientside. Local storage is a 100% browser feature, not aware of any serverside application or code or connected/disconnected logic. By the way, how do you call the Index action when the user is not connected to the sever?? Enough to think about....

Comment: The Index Action is server side, if they're not connected to the internet/server, there is no way that action is running anyway

Answer (score 0):

It would be better building a native application that can do that. As then the business logic will be in the palm of hand, then on return to base, the application can upload the new data.